# Is their a way of passing along typehint to callable in phpstan/intellisense? PHP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense, phpstan

I have a factory method whose signature is similar to this:

```php
/**
 * @param class-string $class
 * @param callable? $callback
 * @return static
 */
public function instance(string $class, callable? $callback);
```

From the first parameter, an instance is created. Rather than the instance being returned, $this is returned instead - so an optional callback can be provided and the factory invokes it, passing the new instance.

What I want to know is - given the string passed is literal, can phpstan/vscode be told that the argument passed to the callable is an instance of my specified class, so that when I refer to the object inside the callable it can make suggestions of available methods/props, and so that phpstan can not grumble about missing methods, without me also typehinting the argument of the callable?

The object created does extend a common base class, but child classes will have their own methods.

Maybe clearer with an example of a call:

```php
$obj->factory(Foo::class, function ($foo) {
   //
}
```

And I’m hoping to avoid repeating the explicit hint:

```php
$obj->factory(Foo::class, function (Foo $foo) {
   //
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics to achieve this.

Check out this example: https://phpstan.org/r/cf596842-d9cb-4996-b2af-08d6683dd366

Basically you'd need a declaration like this one:

```php
/**
 * @template T of object
 * @param class-string<T> $class
 * @param (callable(T):mixed)|null $callback
 * @return static
 */
 public function instance(string $class, callable|null $callback)
```

Here we are saying that the callable has one required argument. And it's type is the object of the first parameter that is passed into the `instance` method.

You can read more about generics [here](https://phpstan.org/blog/generics-in-php-using-phpdocs) and [here](https://phpstan.org/blog/generics-by-examples).

Comment: If I remove all of the generics stuff and, before your ‘dump’ line add $foo->something(), it still appears to pass without error (though the output of the dump then says ‘mixed’ so it’s definitely recognising it WITH the genetics stuff)

Comment: @MarkG I'm sorry. What is your point? If you remove the generic stuff, the callable parameter will be implicitly mixed so `$foo->something()` will not raise an error. That's expected.

Comment: Because in simpler situations, phpstan will moan at me unless it can be 100% sure that the variable has that method, even at much lower levels of checking. And ‘mixed’ type doesn’t seem to be a good guarantee - if the wrong type is passed then I’ll get a fatal. So I’m wondering why it’s not giving any sort of warning.

Comment: From the docs it suggests: “ PHPStan’s rule level 6 isn’t satisfied with implicit mixed, but an explicit one is sufficient” but running at level 9 still doesn’t grumble.

Comment: That issue sounds not related to your issue in the original post. Anyway you can try `checkImplicitMixed: true` in your config file. Maybe that'll report it.